# Setting a function equal to an integral

Tags: equation-solving, functions, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to solve for the constant of integration in simple calculus problems.

```
v[t_] := Integrate[-0.08 t, t] + C
v[t]
```

gives me

```
C - 0.04 t^2
```

Which is good, but then when I try

```
Solve[v[0] == 8]
```

It gives me an error because Im trying to integrate with respect to zero, because my function changes that.

I assume there is something really simple that I'm missing on how to make this work.

Comment: the problem is when you do `v[0]` then inside the function `t=0` and you can't integrate with respect to zero. Another option is to write `Solve[(v[t] /. t -> 0) == 8]`  if you want to keep the delay assignment. And it is a good idea to add the variables you are solving for, so it is explicit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an [immediate assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) to define `v`:

```
v[t_] = Integrate[-0.08 t, t] + c
(*    c - 0.04 t^2    *)

Solve[v[0] == 8]
(*    {{c -> 8.}}    *)
```

[Here's a tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#29979) on the distinction between immediate and delayed assignments.

Alternatively, use a definite integral:

```
t0 = 0;
v0 = 8;
v[t_] = v0 + Integrate[-0.08 s, {s, t0, t}]
(*    8 - 0.04 t^2    *)
```